# Infinite Recursion in kd-tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, graph-theory

I am trying to build a 2-dimensional tree based on recursion. I can sum up the algorithm as follows:

```
>     ALGORITHM BuildKDTree(P,depth)
>     1. if P contains only one point
>     2. then return a leaf storing this point
>     3. else if depth is even
>     4. then split P with a vertical line through median x into P1 and P2 (left and right of the line, respectively)
>     5. else split P with a horizontal line through median y into P1 and P2 like before
>     6. RECURSION STEP -> v_left = BuildKDTree(P1,depth+1)
>     7. RECURSION STEP -> v_right = BuildKDTree(P2,depth+1)
>     8. Create a node v storing the line, make v_left the left child and v_right the right child
>     9. return the node v
```

Since it is the first time I am implementing recursion, I am having quite a lot of problems related to it. The code that I have written so far seems to be in an infinite loop until a segmentation fault is thrown. I was not able to find the bug so far in the code, I would appreciate some help.

```
// Point
struct Point{
    int idx;
    double xpos;
    double ypos;
};

// Node in the k-d tree
struct Node{
    char type;
    Point coord;
    Node* leftChild;
    Node* rightChild;
    double split;
};

// Function to find the median point
int findMedian( const vector<Point>& P, char line ){

    vector<double> positions;
    map<double,int> indices;

    // Store the corresponding positions (vertical or horizontal splitting)
    switch ( line ){

        case 'x':

            for( auto p: P ){
                positions.push_back( p.xpos );
                indices.insert( pair<double,int>(p.xpos,p.idx) );
            }

            break;

        case 'y':

            for( auto p: P ){
                positions.push_back( p.ypos );
                indices.insert( pair<double,int>(p.ypos,p.idx) );
            }

            break;
    }

    sort( positions.begin(), positions.end() );
    cout << positions.size() << endl;
    int middle_pt = (int)floor(positions.size()/2);
    cout << indices[positions[middle_pt]] << "\t" << middle_pt << "\t" << positions[middle_pt] << endl;
    return ( indices[positions[middle_pt]] );

}

// Function to build a k-d tree
Node buildKDTree( vector<Point> P, int depth ){

    Node v;

    // if P contains only one point, return a leaf storing this point;
    // else if depth is even, split P with a vertical line through the median x ..
    // .. into P1 (left of l) and P2 (right of l);
    // when the depth is odd, do the vice versa.
    if( P.size() == 1 ){

        cout << "I am at the leaf!" << endl;

        v.coord = P[0];
        v.type = 'l';
        return v;
    }
    else if( P.size() < 1 ){
        cout << "Points size smaller than 1 " << P.size() << endl;

        v.type = 'n';
        return v;
    }
    else{

        vector<Point> P1; // left of median
        vector<Point> P2; // right of median

        if( depth % 2 == 0 ) {

            // Verical line through median x
            char line = 'x';
            v.type = line;
            int mid_idx = findMedian( P, line );
            v.split = P[mid_idx].xpos;
            v.coord = P[mid_idx];
            for( auto p: P ){
                if( p.xpos < v.split ){
                    //cout << "Through x, left " << "\t" <<  p.xpos << "\t" << mid_coord << endl;
                    P1.push_back( p );
                }
                else{
                    //cout << "Through x, right " << "\t" << p.xpos << "\t" << mid_coord << endl;
                    P2.push_back( p );
                }
            }

        }
        else{

            // Horizontal line through median y
            char line = 'y';
            v.type = line;
            int mid_idx = findMedian( P, line );
            v.split = P[mid_idx].ypos;
            v.coord = P[mid_idx];
            for( auto p: P ){
                if( p.ypos < v.split ){
                    //cout << "Through y, left " << "\t" << p.ypos << "\t" << mid_coord << endl;
                    P1.push_back( p );
                }
                else{
                    //cout << "Through y, right " << "\t" << p.ypos << "\t" << mid_coord << endl;
                    P2.push_back( p );
                }
            }

        }

        cout << "depth is before at " << depth << endl;
        Node temp1 = buildKDTree( P1, depth+1 );
        depth = 2;
        cout << "depth is after at " << depth << endl;
        Node temp2 = buildKDTree( P2, depth+1 );
        v.leftChild = &temp1;
        v.rightChild = &temp2;

        return v;
    }

}

// +++++++


int main( int argc, char *argv[] ){

    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    //++ Get the data
    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    // Choose the data to be used
    const int nsamp = samplePostData;       // Sampling interval
    const double dtSamp = nsamp*dt;         // Time units between two data points

    // Instantiate the data structure
    vector<Cell> cells( M );

    // Set filenames
    char * x_input_file = argv[1];        // Filename for the x data
    char * y_input_file = argv[2];        // Filename for the y data

    // Read the data to the cells
    int sample_cnt = -1;
    int sample_data = 1;
    char getX = 'x';
    readData( cells, x_input_file, getX, sample_cnt, sample_data );
    sample_cnt = -1;
    char getY = 'y';
    readData( cells, y_input_file, getY, sample_cnt, sample_data );

    // Set general simulation variables
    Data simData;
    simData.setNumStep( cells[0].xpos.size() );
    simData.setNumDelay( sqrt( cells[0].xpos.size() ) );
    simData.setNumTotalDelay();

    const double T = simData.getNumStep();              // Total time
    const double D = simData.getNumDelay();             // Last delay time
    const double TD = simData.getNumTotalDelay();       // Total time - last delay time

    // Set the box
    Box box;
    box.setWidth( boxSize_x );
    box.setHeight( boxSize_y );

    const double Lx = box.getWidth();
    const double Ly = box.getHeight();

    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++


    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    //++ Do the analysis
    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    vector<Point> points;
    int i = 1000;
    for( int m = 0; m < M; m++ ){
        Point point_temp;
        point_temp.xpos = (cells[m].xpos[i] - Lx*ifloor(cells[m].xpos[i]/Lx));
        point_temp.ypos = (cells[m].ypos[i] - Ly*ifloor(cells[m].ypos[i]/Ly));
        point_temp.idx = m;
        points.push_back( point_temp );
    }
    vector<Node> tree;
    int depth = 2;
    tree.push_back( buildKDTree( points, depth ) );
    cout << tree.size() << endl;
//    for( auto j: tree ){
//        cout << j.type << "  " << j.coord.idx << "  " << j.coord.xpos << "  " << j.coord.ypos << "  " << j.leftChild->coord.idx << "  " << j.rightChild->coord.idx << "  " << j.leftChild->coord.xpos << "  " << j.rightChild->coord.ypos << "\n";
//    }


}
```

Comment: Sounds like "please debug this for me". My advice is to debug it for yourself. This is a challenge and you will get the most out of it if you accept the challenge. Another point is: Start small. Learn unit testing. Learn [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you don't check for marking the same point twice as the median. It could easily be the case that (especially in dense systems) there are more than one point on the median line. If you don't mark explicitly the points that are used as the median before, then you will just use them again which will create infinite recursion in the tree.

My suggestion is to make a boolean array for each point and as you use these points as the median, just mark them, so that you don't use them again later.